# How do I multiply code text dynamically?

Tags: ruby, loops

I have a code snippet in my Ruby code:

```
while words.size >= 3
  frequency["#{words[0]} #{words[1]} #{words[2]}"] += 1
  words.shift
end
```

I would like to set a variable `i` and, depending on the value of `i`, the appropriate code gets run.  For example is `i=2`:

```
while words.size >= 2
        frequency["#{words[0]} #{words[1]}"] += 1
        words.shift
end
```

Changing the value in the `while` condition is easy, but how do I replicate the body of the loop based on the variable `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this trivially with an if..else statement in your loop:

```
while words.size > 0
  if words.size >= 3
    frequency["#{words[0]} #{words[1]} #{words[2]}"] += 1
  elsif words.size >=2
    frequency["#{words[0]} #{words[1]}"] += 1
  else
    break
  end
  words.shift
end
```

However, this being Ruby, based on how you're creating those keys, it's easy enough to just say:

```
while words.size >= 2
   frequency[words.first(3).join(" ")] += 1
   words.shift
end
```

This will take up to the first three elements from the words array and concatenate them with spaces, giving you your frequency key. In the case that there are only two words left, it'll use both of them.